# In Perl, how do I output (print) all lines that follow a string?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to process a log file. I send it to Perl via `<STDIN>`. I need to output only the summary, which follows a line that contains several equal signs.

The summary is the last bit in the daily log. So, I need everything starting after the line with the `=`s through EOF.

I tried using a `while` loop with a "`next unless`" but I could not get that to work.

Comment: Would those who down voted explain why, so I can learn?

Comment: I didn't, but this much is clear: show your code and sample of input/output. It also makes it easier for you to be precise and articulate in descriptions. The question is extremely incomplete, and unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a flag or two loops.

---

Includes the trigger line in the output:

```
perl -e'
   while (<>) {
      last if /===/;
   }

   if (defined($_)) {
      print;
      while (<>) {
         print;
      }
   }
' log
```

```
perl -ne'print if $print ||= /===/' log
```

---

Doesn't include the trigger line in the output:

```
perl -e'
   while (<>) {
      last if /===/;
   }

   if (defined($_)) {
      while (<>) {
         print;
      }
   }
' log
```

```
perl -ne'last if /===/; END { print while <> }' log
```

```
perl -ne'print if $print; $print ||= /===/' log
```

```
perl -ne'print unless 1 .. /===/' log
```

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, I wanted to be crystal clear in that particular solution, and I was too lazy to check if `do BLOCK while <>;` meant `do BLOCK while defined($_ = <>);`.  [ It does. Curse you for macking me check ;) ]